# Is there a better way to use Ext.apply to combine child/subobjects into another object?

Tags: class, object, extjs, javascript-objects

I'm trying to apply the object properties from objA to objB but I realised Ext.apply is flawed  (or blessing?) in a way where it only applies first level objects together.

Example:

```
var objA = {
    name: 'objA',
    baseParams: {
        cols: [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
};

//used in subclass
var objB = {
    name: 'objB',
    baseParams: {
        limit: 50,
        sort: 'name'
    }
};

//used in baseclass
var objC = {
    name: 'objC',
    baseParams: {
        as_hash: true,
        limit: 20
    }
};

Ext.apply(objB,objA); //used in subclass
Ext.apply(objC,objB); //used in baseclass
```

Example will output:

```
obj = {
    name: 'objA',
    baseParams: {
        cols: [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
};
```

I'd like this output instead (expected output):

```
obj = {
    name: 'objA',
    baseParams: {
        cols: [1,2,3,4,5],
        as_hash: true,
        limit: 50,
        sort: 'name'
    }
};
```

How can I achieve this without doing this?

```
// subclass:
var bpTemp = {};
bpTemp.baseParams = Ext.apply(objB.baseParams, objA.baseParams);
Ext.apply(objB,objA); 
Ext.apply(objB,bpTemp); 

// base class: 
var bpTemp = {};
bpTemp.baseParams = Ext.apply(objC.baseParams, objB.baseParams);
Ext.apply(objC,objB); 
Ext.apply(objC,bpTemp);
```

Comment: interesting question, looking forward to a good solution

Comment: Thanks, still looking for an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change up the way Ext.apply() works so that a 4th argument can be a boolean implying "deep" apply -- this will work with your example (deep defaults to true):

```
Ext.apply = function(o, c, defaults, deep){
    deep = deep!==false;
    // no "this" reference for friendly out of scope calls
    if(defaults){
        Ext.apply(o, defaults);
    }
    if(o && c && typeof c == 'object'){
        for(var p in c){
            o[p] = (deep && Ext.isObject(o[p]) && Ext.isObject(c[p])) ? Ext.apply(o[p], c[p]) : c[p];
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

Comment: FYI -- I defaulted the "deep" argument to true to make your example work... but I would not do that in your app because Ext may depend on non-deep applies internally -- I would explicitly make it "deep" on a case by case basis in your app

Comment: you have a good solution, but it's not practical nor advisable to change a library function as it may affect other people using it (especially if it's a commonly used method). I'm marking this as an answer because it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a recursive solution, with a few special cases, as below:

```
function deepApply(receiver, config, defaults) {
    if (defaults) {
        deepApply(receiver, defaults);
    }
    if (receiver && config && typeof config == 'object') {
        for (var p in config) {
            if (typeof config[p] != 'object' || Ext.isArray(config[p])) {
                receiver[p] = config[p];
            } else {
                if (typeof receiver[p] != 'object') {
                    receiver[p] = {};
                }
                deepApply(receiver[p], config[p]);
            }
        }
    }
    return receiver;
}
```